# Excel Function - Can't figure out the equation needed

Tags: excel, vba, math

I am using a loop to figure out the ending rent after an increase of 15% per year.
This works fine.

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As range)
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler '<--| be sure to catch any error and enable events handling back
    Select Case Target.Address

        Case "$F$15"
           'Recalculate as necessary Using Looping
          amount = range("F12").Value
          For counter = 1 To range("F15").Value
             Debug.Print counter;

             amount = amount + (range("F12").Value * 0.15)
           Next
           range("F16").Value = amount
```

The problem for me is that I wish to have the same kind of loop to figure out the opposite scenario also. I want to be able to Figure out what the Beginning rent would have been depending on the years entered. (F21) Assuming that we know the ending Rent.
[image: Excel Screen Shot]

So need to figure out F20. 
I asked my son and he worked it out using algebra but couldn't help me with excel.
Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Just to be clear,  it looks to me like you are not compounding the 15% increase. If it is for 2 years,  you add 30%. For 3 years you add 45%.  Is that correct?  Is that what you want?

Comment: from you code , you are basically doing `ending_rent = starting_rent * (1+years*rate)`. to get the starting rent just use` starting_rent = ending_rent / (1+years*rate)`

Comment: `F16 = F12*(1+F15*0.15)` and `F20 = F19/(1+F21*0.15)`

Comment: However, since the rent has to increase every year, you should increase the last years rent by 15% i.e. `amount = amount + (amount  * 0.15)`

Comment: The for loop that I have is working fine for Figuring out the Ending Rent (F16). I want it to be simple interest not compounded. I will look tomorrow if nightcrawlers "ending_rent = starting_rent * (1+years*rate)" comes up with the same answer.(which seems to be that I won't need a for loop to do this then. Then I will Try the "F20 = F19/(1+F21*0.15)"  which is what I was looking to figure out if I didn't know F20. My math skills are sketchy which is why I used the loop to begin with.  Thanks. Need to do this tomorrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have refactored your code, using both a looping method and a non-looping method:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As range)
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler '<--| be sure to catch any error and enable events handling back
    Dim factor As Double
    Dim period As Integer
    Dim amount As Double
    Select Case Target.Address

        Case "$F$15"
            period = Range("F15").Value
            amount = Range("F12").Value

            'Recalculate as necessary Using Looping
            factor = 1
            For counter = 1 To period
                Debug.Print counter;
                factor = factor + 0.15
            Next
            Range("F16").Value = amount * factor

            'alternate method without looping
            Range("F16").Value = amount * (1 + period * 0.15)
            'which can also be written in VBA as
            [F16] = [F12] * (1 + [F15] * 0.15)

        Case "$F$21"
            period = Range("F21").Value
            amount = Range("F19").Value

            'Recalculate as necessary Using Looping
            factor = 1
            For counter = 1 To period
                factor = factor + 0.15
            Next
            Range("F20").Value = amount / factor

            'alternate method without looping
            Range("F20").Value = amount / (1 + period * 0.15)
            'which can also be written in VBA as
            [F20] = [F19] / (1 + [F21] * 0.15)
```